# Is Collections.copy broken (in OpenJDK 6)?

Tags: java

***Sometimes I seem to be quite inefficient. When I was nearly finished typing this, I managed to find the appropriate bug report at Sun. I then thought well, might as well post it, having the screenshot and all. Answer follows.***

I know, "SELECT isn't broken", and it's always my fault. But here, I really don't get why it should be. My code snippet:

```
List<IGraphEdge> rgSrc = this._rgGetPath();
List<IGraphEdge> rgDst = new ArrayList<IGraphEdge>(rgSrc.size());
Collections.copy(rgDst, rgSrc);
```

This throws an `IndexOutOfBoundException` with the message

> ```
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest
>         at java.util.Collections.copy(Collections.java:548)
> ```

In the debugger, when I step into Collections.copy, the two `ArrayList` instances look like this:

[Debugger view http://static.theuprightape.net/ql/img/debugger.png](http://static.theuprightape.net/ql/img/debugger.png)

So, there's the capacity in `dest` to hold that one element from `src`, although, naturally, the `size` of `dest` is still 0, after all, this is what I want to change by calling `copy()`.

Looking at the source code of the OpenJDK implementation, it's clear why the error is thrown:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
    int srcSize = src.size();
    if (srcSize > dest.size())
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Source does not fit in dest");
```

So please tell me, is that a bug, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not looking at the *capacity*, it's looking at the size. That is, the destination should contain elements, which are to be overwritten by the source list.

I've never run into a case where this would be useful. Usually what you want is a copy constructor in one of the `List` implementations, or the `addAll` method of the `Collection` interface.

Comment: I took "must be at least as long" to mean "must have at least the capacity to contain all items".

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't the first to run into this, but it really is always your fault. According to the response to [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6305513) at Sun, `Collections.copy` is not intended to be used like this, you should use `List.appendAll()` instead.

So I fixed my code to look like this and it worked:

```
List<IGraphEdge> rgSrc = this._rgGetPath();
List<IGraphEdge> rgDst = new ArrayList<IGraphEdge>(rgSrc.size());
rgDst.addAll(rgSrc);
```

Duh.

Comment: Better would be: `List<IGraphEdge> rgDst = new ArrayList<IGraphEdge>(rgSrc)`

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for Collection.copy:

> Copies all of the elements from one
>   list into another. After the
>   operation, the index of each copied
>   element in the destination list will
>   be identical to its index in the
>   source list. *The destination list must
>   be at least as long as the source
>   list*. If it is longer, the remaining
>   elements in the destination list are
>   unaffected.

I agree with you that it's not terribly intuitive, but it seems like what you're really trying to do is more like clone().

Comment: I took "must be at least as long" to mean "must have at least the same capacity", which isn't what it *did* mean. `clone()`, as long as it's shallow, is what I want here, but for lists specifically, I can in fact use `addAll` or the *constructor of ArrayList* (duh).

Answer (score 1):

The Javadocs say:

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if
>   the destination list is too small to
>   contain the entire source List.

So it seems to be conforming to the spec.